# Not able to make a query that give me the result that I want in MySQL with 4 tables junction

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-5.6, select

I need help to adjust my query to be able to have the result show in bottom.

This is my DB illustration:

[image]

And this is the command  CREATE TABLE for each table:

```
CREATE TABLE `produits` (
  `sku` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `produits` (`sku`, `description`) VALUES
('1', 'Produit 1'),
('2', 'Produit 2'),
('3', 'Produit 3');


CREATE TABLE `produitssite` (
   `pssku` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `psloc` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   `psabcd` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `produitssite` (`pssku`, `psloc`, `psabcd`) VALUES
('1', 'A', 'd'),
('1', 'B', 'd'),
('2', 'A', 'c'),
('3', 'A', 'b'),
('4', 'C', 'd');


CREATE TABLE `stocksminmax` (
  `smmsku` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `smmloc` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `smmphy` float(20,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `stocksminmax` (`smmsku`, `smmloc`, `smmphy`) VALUES
('1', 'A', 10.00),
('1', 'B', 20.00),
('2', 'A', 20.00),
('3', 'B', 5.00),
('4', 'B', 10.00);


CREATE TABLE `ventes` (
  `ventesku` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ventelocalisation` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `vente1805` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `ventes` (`ventesku`, `ventelocalisation`, `vente1805`) VALUES
('1', 'A', 500),
('1', 'B', 250),
('2', 'B', 600),
('3', 'A', 400),
('4', 'A', 100);
```

Here are the three requests that I try to obtain in 1:

```
SELECT * FROM produits RIGHT JOIN stocksminmax ON sku = smmsku

SELECT * FROM produits RIGHT JOIN produitssite ON sku = pssku

SELECT * FROM produits RIGHT JOIN ventes ON sku = ventesku
```

But I also try to JOIN the location on each table in my request : smmloc, psloc and venteloc

This is what I try to obtain:
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want to be able to do is join the three tables with both a SKU and a location using a `FULL JOIN`; this joins rows where the indicated columns match, and also includes rows from *both* tables where the indicated fields do *not* match.

Unfortunately, MySQL 5.6 doesn't implement `FULL JOIN`. The standard workaround is to do something like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1
         LEFT  JOIN table 2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1
         RIGHT JOIN table 2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
 WHERE t1.id IS NULL
;
```

This gives you the results of the `LEFT JOIN` of the tables, and then unions in the results of the `RIGHT JOIN` of the tables, excluding the rows that would have been in the `LEFT JOIN` results.

The exclusion deals with the fact that both the `LEFT JOIN` and the `RIGHT JOIN` will return whatever rows an `INNER JOIN` would return. We want those rows - but we don't want to include each of them twice!

So, I built this query in three steps:

- First, I built the query to return the rows from `ventes` and `produitssite`.
- Then, I used that query as a subquery (identified as `s1`, for "step 1"), and joined its results to `stocksminmax`.
- Finally, I used the second query as a subquery (identified as `s2`, for "step 2"), and `LEFT JOIN`ed those results to `produits`. For this final step, since it looks like you don't want to list and products that don't have a match in at least one of the three other tables, we don't have to do both a `LEFT JOIN` and a `RIGHT JOIN`.

Here's the query I got:

```
SELECT `sku`,`description`
      ,`smmsku`,`smmloc`,`smmphy`
      ,`pssku`,`psloc`,`psabcd`
      ,`ventesku`,`ventelocalisation`,`vente1805`
  FROM (
        SELECT `theSku`
              ,`theLoc`
              ,`smmsku`,`smmloc`,`smmphy`
              ,`pssku`,`psloc`,`psabcd`
              ,`ventesku`,`ventelocalisation`,`vente1805`
          FROM (SELECT `pssku` as theSku
                      ,`psloc` as theLoc
                      ,`pssku`,`psloc`,`psabcd`
                      ,`ventesku`,`ventelocalisation`,`vente1805`
                  FROM produitssite ps
                         LEFT  JOIN ventes v ON ps.pssku = v.ventesku
                                            AND ps.psloc = v.ventelocalisation
                UNION ALL
                SELECT `ventesku` as theSku
                      ,`ventelocalisation` as theLoc
                      ,`pssku`,`psloc`,`psabcd`
                      ,`ventesku`,`ventelocalisation`,`vente1805`
                  FROM produitssite ps
                         RIGHT JOIN ventes v ON ps.pssku = v.ventesku
                                            AND ps.psloc = v.ventelocalisation
                 WHERE ps.pssku IS NULL
               ) s1
                 LEFT  JOIN stocksminmax smm ON s1.theSku = smm.smmsku
                                            AND s1.theLoc = smm.smmloc
        UNION ALL
        SELECT `smmsku` as theSku
              ,`smmloc` as theLoc
              ,`smmsku`,`smmloc`,`smmphy`
              ,`pssku`,`psloc`,`psabcd`
                ,`ventesku`,`ventelocalisation`,`vente1805`
          FROM (SELECT `pssku` as theSku
                      ,`psloc` as theLoc
                      ,`pssku`,`psloc`,`psabcd`
                      ,`ventesku`,`ventelocalisation`,`vente1805`
                  FROM produitssite ps
                         LEFT  JOIN ventes v ON ps.pssku = v.ventesku
                                            AND ps.psloc = v.ventelocalisation
                UNION ALL
                SELECT `ventesku` as theSku
                      ,`ventelocalisation` as theLoc
                      ,`pssku`,`psloc`,`psabcd`
                      ,`ventesku`,`ventelocalisation`,`vente1805`
                  FROM produitssite ps
                         RIGHT JOIN ventes v ON ps.pssku = v.ventesku
                                            AND ps.psloc = v.ventelocalisation
                 WHERE ps.pssku IS NULL
               ) s1
                 RIGHT JOIN stocksminmax smm ON s1.theSku = smm.smmsku
                                            AND s1.theLoc = smm.smmloc
         WHERE s1.theSku IS NULL
       ) s2
         LEFT  JOIN produits p ON s2.theSku = p.sku
;
```

I believe the results match what you expected - you can see them (and the query, working) in this [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tWzfPWPghdxqbU7DiG2ZQc/2).

Answer (score 0):

This is the most logical answer to your requirement:

```
SELECT `sku`, `description`,`smmsku`, `smmloc`, `smmphy`,`pssku`, `psloc`, `psabcd`,`ventesku`, `ventelocalisation`, `vente1805` FROM ventes
LEFT JOIN stocksminmax ON ventesku = smmsku AND smmloc = ventelocalisation
LEFT JOIN produitssite ON ventesku = pssku AND psloc = ventelocalisation
LEFT JOIN produits ON ventesku = sku
```